# Is there a difference between this configuration settings for Bolt on Memgraph?

Tags: graph-databases, bolt, memgraphdb

When defining configuration settings for Bolt that will connect to `localhost` what is the preferred way?

- `--bolt-address=0.0.0.0`
- `--bolt-address=127.0.0.1`
- `--bolt-address=localhost`

Can I use any of these three methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to use `127.0.0.1`. These three addresses can resolve to the same resource, but there are some situations when this will not happen.

`0.0.0.0` is all IPv4 addresses for devices on a machine, internally and externally facing so it's sometimes a security risk. `127.0.0.1` is IPv4 loopback. localhost resolves to either `127.0.0.1` (IPv4 loopback) or `::1` (IPv6 loopback). If you use `127.0.0.1` in one place, you can't necessarily expect localhost to resolve to the same address, because of potential ipv6 confusion.

Best practices are to specify a specific, non-0.0.0.0 address and not `localhost`, due to the ipv6 confusion issue that can lead to connection failures.

You can also find some additional details on  Superuser site question "[What's the difference between 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0?](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0)"